# Full-calendar - combine Years view and language change

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to change language in FullCalendar with year view. I got 2 examples for Years view and Language support here :[Lang support](https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.9.1/demos/languages.html) , [Year View](https://libraries.io/bower/fullcalendar-yearview)

Problem is - i can't get both to work together... I've tried to load both file like this :

```
<script src='js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>// years support
<script src='js/old/fullcalendar.js'></script>// Lang support
```

And i also tried combining the code manually - but i found it time consuming and not so efficient....

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need `js/old/fullcalendar.js`, as you are using newer minified version of js lib.

Using new and old two js libs of same plugin is highly avoidable as it may create conflicts and you may end up with two implementation/versions of a function.

They have provided base library, this contains year view, refer [Year Demo](http://epsy.ldtp.net/fullcalendar/demos/year.html)

`<script src='../fullcalendar.min.js'></script>`

For language they are using another js `lang-all.js` with base fullcalendar.min.js and it perfectly working, refer [Language and Year Demo](http://epsy.ldtp.net/fullcalendar/demos/languages.html)

```
<script src='../lang-all.js'></script>
```